# Sort array to new 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```js
[
  {
    "id": 3401,
    "league": {
      "id": 4140,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  }
]
```

I have a lot of such objects in the array. How can I sort/format my array such way I got a new array/dictionary with objects sorted by value of `"id"` in `"league"` from example it's `4140`. Now i have a normal array but I want something sorted either by key-value something like 4140: [objects from array with league id 4140] or 2d array sorted `[[array with all objects containing league with value "id" of 4140], [array with objects with league value id 4141], etc..]`. Do i need to use `map` or something like that ? I am pretty new to Javascript.

Here is what I expect to get in code.

```js
//THIS is what I want to get in the end...
[
  {
    "league": "League Cup",
    "tournaments": [
      {
        "id": 3402,
        "league": {
          "id": 4141,
          "image_url": "pngurl.png",
          "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          "name": "League Cup",
          "slug": "league-slug",
          "url": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3403,
        "league": {
          "id": 4141,
          "image_url": "pngurl.png",
          "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          "name": "League Cup",
          "slug": "league-slug",
          "url": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "league": "League Cup 2",
    "tournaments": [
      {
        "id": 3401,
        "league": {
          "id": 4145,
          "image_url": "pngurl.png",
          "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          "name": "League Cup 2",
          "slug": "league-slug",
          "url": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3405,
        "league": {
          "id": 4145,
          "image_url": "pngurl.png",
          "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          "name": "League Cup 2",
          "slug": "league-slug",
          "url": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: please add some more data, thewanted result **and** your try.

Comment: Can you add a fraction of code as you need?

We need a little more information about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through it and group them in a new object based on your league id.

Example:

```
const output = {};
const input = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "league": {
      "id": 7,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "league": {
      "id": 7,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "league": {
      "id": 8,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  }
];

input.forEach(x => {
  if (!output[x.league.id]) {
    output[x.league.id] = [];
  }

  output[x.league.id].push(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array of object you should use sort() function of an array

```js
var yourArray = [{
    "id": 3401,
    "league": {
      "id": 4140,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3405,
    "league": {
      "id": 4145,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3402,
    "league": {
      "id": 4143,
      "image_url": "pngurl.png",
      "modified_at": "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
      "name": "League Cup",
      "slug": "league-slug",
      "url": null
    }
  }
]

yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.league.id < b.league.id) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.league.id > b.league.id) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})

//Output will be sorted array
console.log(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and apply `sort` on each `object.tournaments`

```js
const sorted = (arr) =>
  arr.map((obj) => ({
    ...obj,
    tournaments: obj.tournaments.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id),
  }));
  
const data = [
  {
    league: "League Cup",
    tournaments: [
      {
        id: 3403,
        league: {
          id: 4141,
          image_url: "pngurl.png",
          modified_at: "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          name: "League Cup",
          slug: "league-slug",
          url: null,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 3401,
        league: {
          id: 4141,
          image_url: "pngurl.png",
          modified_at: "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          name: "League Cup",
          slug: "league-slug",
          url: null,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    league: "League Cup 2",
    tournaments: [
      {
        id: 3405,
        league: {
          id: 4145,
          image_url: "pngurl.png",
          modified_at: "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          name: "League Cup 2",
          slug: "league-slug",
          url: null,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 3401,
        league: {
          id: 4145,
          image_url: "pngurl.png",
          modified_at: "2019-02-19T15:29:07Z",
          name: "League Cup 2",
          slug: "league-slug",
          url: null,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];



console.log(sorted(data));
```